# Set IPN email if paypal payment failed

Tags: magento2, email, payment-methods, paypal

I want to send a custom mail to customer if the Paypal payment has been failed using IPN module.

In short in Paypal IPN module from where I can identify paypal payment has failed over there I can set custom mail.